# can i use firebase for text sms like way to sms for marketing not for authentication

Tags: firebase, sms

I have 8000 contacts to send SMS I want to send them SMS can I do it with the help of firebase.
I want to send SMS from online to phone number. can I do this with the help of firebase? without any app installed in their phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Firebase does not offer general SMS services.